# What symbol can be used to denote an assignment of a left hand side value to a right hand side variable?

Tags: notation

If I am doing a calculation that involves some intermediate value, for example:

$intermediate = \frac{17}{13} = 1.30769230769 \\
answer = intermediate + 10.1345 \\
answer = 1.30769230769 + 10.1345 \\$

what symbol can I use for left to right hand assignment to replace the "ASSIGN TO" so that:

$intermediate = \frac{17}{13} = 1.30769230769$ ASSIGN TO $a_v$ 

$\\
answer = intermediate + 10.1345 \\
answer = a_v + 10.1345 \\$

which saves having  to copy out the $1.30769230769$ again when it may be stored in a variable on a calculator and as such can be used directly from there. $a_v$ is just a made up variable in the context of the working.

Comment: You can just say "Let $a_v = 17/13$.

Comment: @littleO Sometimes working is done up against the left hand margin, before it is realised that you will want to assign the calculated value to a variable. Also if the calculated value is a large surd for example, it would be a pain to write on a new line Let a = large surd and would be nicer if there was a way to quickly assign the calculated value without copying it down more than once.

Comment: Against the left margin?  (Who doesn't use a computer for writing?)  Still use words.  "Write $a_v$ for this value." or "Call this $a_v$."

Comment: Mathematics variables do not support traditional assignment. If you are actually referring to a variable in Excel/Mathematica/Python/whatever, please specify that. For mathematical writing, @GEdgar 's ", call it $a_v$" should suffice.